# HTML UI with SDL2

Tags: sdl2, ui-design, c++, html

I realized that I need an HTML-like UI in my game, because by myself I wouldn't be able to achieve such effects (divs, text, coloring, and styling).

So I started to look around for a HTML Engine for C++, and I found [Sciter](http://sciter.com/) but it's built completely on top of the Win API and I just can't get it to work/debug (because it lacks of decent DOCs too). Now, I'm wondering if there is some very simple engine (I just need HTML and CSS, no JS) and SDL friendly (should have some functions like create, update, render, ...).

Comment: Sciter's author is here... I've added an option to use Sciter inside DirectX http://sciter.com/sciter-and-directx/ and there is an ongoing project for the same with OpenGL and so SDL. That's just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com). I have integrated it to SDL before and the process was fast. The biggest thing you have to deal with is translating SDL events to Awesomium. Otherwise the rendering is really easy, you can just query pixel data from Awesomium into an SDL surface IIRC, and then render that to your game.

Comment: Garry's Mod uses Awesomium, and though I haven't used it myself, other people frequently complain about it being outdated and buggy.

Comment: Garry's mod was released in 2004 which might have an effect regarding being outdated.

Comment: @immibis Garry's Mod uses Source GUI, doesn't it? So Source is using Awesomium, no?

Comment: @Xriuk It supports Source's GUI components, and a bunch of GMod-specific ones.

Comment: Ok, so, I took a look at this, and it seems to work only on Visual C++. And I'm using DevCpp (MinGW), do you know some workaround?

Comment: Ok, I'm managing to switch to Visual Studio. But I wanted to ask you something: I read that awesomium can be ["heavy"](http://steamcommunity.com/app/4000/discussions/1/558747288148680197/#c540744475460862611), did you have any problems with your project?

Comment: I only use Visual Studio so I don't know anything about workarounds. I only used Awesomium for a short period of time, but I did not have any problems with it.